# Firebase Cloud Function onDelete variable param length

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code

```
//index.js
export const deletePicture = functions.region("europe-west1").database
  .ref("galleries/{galleryId}/{pictureId}")
  .onDelete(pictures.deletePicture)

//pictures.js
export const deletePicture = (snap, {params: {galleryId}}) => {
  console.log("Image deletion detected in the database, deleting images 
  from the Storage...")
  const {fileName} = snap.val()
  const bucket = storage.bucket()
  const baseURL = `galleries/${galleryId}`
  // Thumbnails
  const promises = [sizes
    .map(size => 
      bucket.file(`${baseURL}/thumb_${size}_${fileName}`).delete())]
  // Original
  promises.push(bucket.file(`${baseURL}/${fileName}`).delete())

  return Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(() => console.log(`All versions of ${fileName} are now deleted.`))
}
```

In my realtime database and Storage, I have the following structure:

```
galleries
|_rooms
| |_roomId
|   |_picture
|_foods
  |_picture
```

Is there any way that the above mentioned `onDelete` Cloud Function would trigger for the deletion of either of the pictures? The difference here is that the rooms picture is one level deeper, so I think that `pictureId` does not match `roomId/picture`.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions has no knowledge of the meaning of your JSON. So the trigger for delete of `galleries/{galleryId}/{pictureId}`, really just means that this function gets triggered whenever a node at the second level under `galleries` gets trigged.

In the structure you show, that means that this function will trigger whenever `/galleries/room/roomId` or `/galleries/foods/picture` gets deleted. The first of these will get triggered when you delete the last picture from a room.

Comment: So I should either restructure the code, so that my room pictures are at the same level, or write another trigger for the rooms?

Comment: Both could be valid options. If you have multiple triggers for the same functionality, make sure to: 1) isolate the overlapping code into a regular JavaScript function that you hen call from both cases, 2) ensure there is no overlap in the triggers, i.e. that each database write can only trigger one of your Cloud Functions.